# Separating data SQL

Tags: sql

I need help viewing my data stored in table.

I have a table called `student` with the following attributes:

- StudentID, Name, Level, Course

What I want to do is to show level and number of students enrolled on that level in the following form:

```
LEVEL  |  NumOfStudents
```

Any suggestions how I can succeed this or which method I should use?

Comment: This screams homework to me. Show us what you have tried (psuedocode? actual code? etc).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you say attributes, I think you mean columns. If so, try:

```
SELECT level, count(studentid) AS NumOfStudents
FROM student
GROUP BY level
```

Comment: Glad it worked.  Please mark my answer as accepted if you're all set so others know the question is no longer open.